# javascript array object filter on keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript db in the format

```
var db = [
{ "id": "500020", "type": "0", "address": "", "firstName": "bob", "lastName": "builder", "title": "Mr", "managerId": "0", "officeId": "222", "cellPhone": "", "officePhone": "001221212121", "email": "myemail@domain.com", "Hours": "", "Custface": "", "Hearloop": "", "Parking": "", "Toilets": "", "Wheelchair": "", "OfficeType": "", "lat": "", "lon": "", "Company": "mycompany","image": "1111" },
{ "id": "500025", "type": "0", "address": "", "firstName": "danny", "lastName": "mccanny", "title": "Mr", "managerId": "0", "officeId": "0", "cellPhone": "", "officePhone": "012545251", "email": "Danny@mccanny.com", "Hours": "", "Custface": "", "Hearloop": "", "Parking": "", "Toilets": "", "Wheelchair": "", "OfficeType": "", "lat": "", "lon": "", "Company": "dannycompany","image": "500025" }
]
```

I then reference it like this

```
this.employees = db;
```

in a function I then filter it when a user searches like this

```
    var employees = this.employees.filter(function (element) {
        var fullname = element.firstname + " " + element.lastname;
        return fullname.tolowercase().indexof(searchkey.tolowercase()) > -1;
    });
```

the problem is that it is searching every element of the object not just the `firstName` and the `lastName`.

Can someone tell me how to get it to filter on just the first and last name using either javascript or jquery

Comment: First thing fist...Typo mistake...in `element.firstName`, `element.lastName` and function is `indexOf`, not `indexof`.., and `toLowerCase`, not `tolowercase`

Comment: `it is searching every element of the object` - do you mean every *property* of the object? Where do you see that happening exactly? It's clearly searching over the concatenation of the properties you've mentioned.

Comment: Please provide enough code to replicate the issue. Statement is contrary to code shown once typo is fixed ( which should have thrown error in first place)

Comment: Also, as @Rakesh_Kumar indicates, JS is case sensitive. So `firstName` is not equivalent to `firstname` and so on.

Comment: @tramp-man do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/0mt1ruvh/

Comment: Your absolutely right thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can use jquery grep method to filter the data and the code will be

```
var employees = $.grep(this.employees, function(element){
    var fullname = element.firstName + " " + element.lastName;
    return fullname.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchkey.toLowerCase()) > -1;
})
```